# web app is changing URL automatically when POST/Submit is fired

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5

I have an .aspx page in a folder called "Graphics".

In that page(DisplayArena.aspx), I use jQuery.load to "load" another .aspx page into a div like this:

```
//in DisplayArena.aspx
//load from the "BossEncounters" folder
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainGamingArena").load('../BossEncounters/encounterGenerator.aspx?ID=<%= Session("currentID") %>');
});
```

It loads the encounter generator fine, but whenever I need to submit/post anything on that page, it thinks that the URL should be "/Graphics/encounterGenerator.aspx" instead of "/BossEncounters/encounterGenerator.aspx".

So I end up getting a 404 error and the error page says:

> requested URL:  /Graphics/encounterGenerator.aspx

I am not sure where or why it's changing the path like that. It's not anywhere in my code, it must be some kind of behind-the-scenes processing and I can't find it.

My project is Visual Studio is setup like this:

```
Game_WebApp
   /Graphics
   /BossEncounters
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use an IFrame instead of div

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load another ASPX page dynamically to an ASPX page. It ends up with two form tag like this -

```
<form method="post" ..>
   <form method="post" ..>
   ...
   </form>
</form>
```

As the result, you cannot post the page back to server. ASP.NET Web Form Technology doesn't allow two form tags in a single page. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Oh I see. Even if there is no form in the encounterGenerator.aspx page?  I do my submitting/posting via a javascript/jquery ajax call to an API controller.  I don't have a <form> element on that page.

Comment: Although you do not see to form tag on initial page load, the browser finally ends up with two forms tag after `load` function is called. You might want to look into different technology like ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Oh I see.  So I could fix this by changing the .aspx to just a simple .html page?

Comment: Yes, you can load simple .html file as long as it doesn't have html, body and form tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a part of a page, try to implement your own [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx), this is exactly why they were introduced. It's a quite similar to `aspx`, with same event cycle, and it can be easily [created from a web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x6sx01c.aspx).

Your code will be like:

```
<!-- DisplayArena.aspx -->
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Boss" 
    Src="~/Controls/EncounterGenerator.ascx" %>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <uc:Boss id="boss1" 
        runat="server"
    />
</form>
</body>
```

`Session` will be available, so no need to pass with markup. Also you can provide some parameters to your user control by properties. I encourage you to read whole MSDN section regarding this.

Another way to do this is to use a [`Server.Transfer`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/server-transfer) method, but this is actually calling two webpages one after another, not one inside another.